# Change a pandas Data Frame to Hugging Face Dataset for Question Answering

Tags: dataframe, nlp, information-retrieval, nlp-question-answering, huggingface-datasets

I should change a pandas Data Frame to the Hugging Face Dataset object, this will be used in the Question Answering Task and I want to fine-tune the model for further prediction on my custom dataset. The problem is that I just have questions and answers in two separate columns, I saw that there is need for context and the start position for the answer as well. I do not know how to get first position for the answer, and I am not sure if I can do this task without any context, can you help me with that?

I did try to have the context and asnwer as the same data columns, but still I need to get the first index porintion for answers.